# How to correct strange behavior in Pandas styled dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have a pandas dataframe and I am styling one column with the following function:

```
def alta_baja(val):

    color = 'black'

    if (val <= 10.0):

        color = 'green'

    elif (val >= 19.0):
    
        color = 'red'

    return 'color: %s' % color

df.style.applymap(alta_baja, subset=['MEDIA'])
```

It was working fine until anaconda was updated then the function started putting trailing zeros.

[image]

A workaround would be to remove the zeros from the stylized object.

I am using Jupyter Notebook 6.0.3

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
    df.style.applymap(alta_baja, subset=['MEDIA']).format({'MEDIA': "{:.1f}"})
```